# Displaying all the images from all of my articles

Tags: plugins, images, gallery

I'm trying to replicate [that codepen](https://codepen.io/pbouigue/pen/eYJQXvP) but using php wordpress. Basically I want my blogpost images displaying in another div and it changes every time you select another menu.

Thanks for the help.
Here is my code:

```
<?php 
$images = get_field('gallery');
if( $images ): ?>
<ul>
    <?php foreach( $images as $image ): ?>
        <li>    
                    <img src="<?php echo esc_url($image['sizes']['thumbnail']); ?>" alt="<?php echo esc_attr($image['alt']); ?>" />
                <p><?php echo esc_html($image['caption']); ?></p>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I have noticed that `$images = get_field('gallery');` stores the image of the latests post before its called. So I guess it has something to do with that. Now I wish I could just get all the images somewhere and apply them a data id corresponding to my articles. That is why I have a `$counter = -1;`.

Here is the complete code:

```
<div class="four">



    <?php
    $counter = -1;
// the query
    $all_posts = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'post', 'post_status' => 'publish', 'posts_per_page' => -1 ) );

    if ( $all_posts->have_posts() ) :
        ?>

        <ul>
            <?php while ( $all_posts->have_posts() ) : $all_posts->the_post(); $counter++ ?>
                <li class='sub-menu'> <a href='#' class="exposition"  data-id="divId<?php echo $counter; ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>  <ul>
                    <li><?php the_content(); ?>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
</ul>

<?php else : ?>
<?php endif; ?>



</div>
<div class="five">

<?php 
$images = get_field('gallery');
if( $images ): ?>
    <ul>    <div class="slide-photos" id="divId<?php echo $counter; ?>" data-id="divId<?php echo $counter; ?>"> 
        <?php foreach( $images as $image ): ?>
            <li>    
                <div class="photos-ind"><img id="divId<?php echo $counter; ?>" class="slide-photos" src="<?php echo esc_url($image['sizes']['thumbnail']); ?>" data-id="divId<?php echo $counter; ?>"/></div>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
           </div>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>


</div>
</div>
```

All it does from now, is just displaying the latests post's images correctly, what I would like is that its able to detect which post i'm clicking and display the image corresponding.

Comment: I'm not 100% clear on what you're trying to do. Perhaps you could make a mock of the HTML that you want to get out? doesn't have to be complete, just to show the result you want.

Comment: Sorry it's not very clear... I have edited my post to make it a bit better.
I'm trying to replicate this [https://codepen.io/pbouigue/pen/eYJQXvP] codepen but using php for my wordpress.
Actually, I would like to be able to have images in each posts and to display them and be able to switch to specific one each time to open a new menu.

Comment: Ah, i see. That's a lot of code to write in one answer so you might need to break this down into separate questions and approach it in pieces. I would suggest instead of using your own ID with your `counter` variable you use the post ID, then find the images **by** post ID and use that also for the ID of the images.

Comment: well, I see.
besides all that, the major point to me is just that I would like to make the image displays properly.
About the cleaning, I think it will be something i'll do after I get something at least working a bit...
Thanks for your fast reply

Comment: I edited the post to make this more clear and to go step by step :)

Comment: also, I'm not again using the post ID, which is, you are right, a way better solution to do, but all of that seems very vague...

Comment: You may get more specific answers by asking smaller self contained questions. E.g. by breaking the problem down into parts, which also helps in programming